# как можно использовать Python совместно с Kotlin

Tags: python, kotlin

Например у меня будет парсер на python, и мне нужно использовать данные этого парсера в моб.приложении.
Можно попробовать сохранять данные в отдельный файл, потом считывать этот файл, но, если будет много данных, тогда это немного напряжно.
Как это можно сделать проще? Можно ссылки на статьи(англ и русский)

Comment: Вариант - бэкэнд сервер на Python (не на телефоне, где-то отдельно), а приложение на Kotlin с ним работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятнее всего Вам необходимо использовать сокеты, т.к. парсер и приложение на kotlin будут запущенны операционной системой разными процессами.

[Пример создания сокета клиента на Kotlin](https://ktor.io/docs/servers-raw-sockets.html#client)

[Документация и примеры для создания сокетов на Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html)